# Why my JTextarea doesn't wrap correctly?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

I'm really surprised about my JTextArea. Following [JTextArea JAVAdoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) i tried to create a JTextArea of a long string and wanted to have my lines wrap automatically.

```
JTextArea text = new JTextArea(myLongString,10,100);
text.setLineWrap(true);
text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
myContainer.add(text);
```

But in fact my text is going outside of my frame and the number of char by line is about 180.
Maybe i didn't understand something or the problem is in layout management. But to avoid the layout complication i reduce it to a basic frame>panel>textarea.

Be aware that English isn't my native language.

```
public class myTest extends JFrame
{

    public myTest()
    {
        JPanel simplePanel = new JPanel();
        String alongString = "Accusata consulatu vix ad, eruditi albucius liberavisse est no. Platonem reprehendunt qui ea. Dicta recteque referrentur an his, id facete maiorum vulputate vim. At suas oratio mnesarchum quo. Quidam omnium necessitatibus ex sea, vix soleat quaerendum conclusionemque ut, case malorum nam an.No quis suas discere nam, nam ex nostro fastidii vivendum. Sed cu nobis ullamcorper. Has at doctus ponderum honestatis. In facer dicam corpora vis.";
        JTextArea myText = new JTextArea(alongString,10,100 );

        this.setSize(800, 600);

        myText.setLineWrap(true);
        myText.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        simplePanel.add(myText);
        this.add(simplePanel);
        this.validate();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new myTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). *"..English isn't my native language"*  Your English is good, but a screenshot speaks any language.

Comment: BTW - I always recommend to look at the latest version of the JavaDocs (for [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) or anything else).  They warn you of the things that might have been deprecated in 1.5.

Comment: It seems to work with a boxlayout on the JPanel.

Comment: Ok, i think that JTextArea need a Layout on its container to get the limit of its lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your jtext area is inisde a panel with the default layout manager. You need to change it something else. Check out the modified code below and tell me if it works for you.

```
public MyTest()
{


    String alongString = "Accusata consulatu vix ad, eruditi albucius liberavisse est no. Platonem reprehendunt qui ea. Dicta recteque referrentur an his, id facete maiorum vulputate vim. At suas oratio mnesarchum quo. Quidam omnium necessitatibus ex sea, vix soleat quaerendum conclusionemque ut, case malorum nam an.No quis suas discere nam, nam ex nostro fastidii vivendum. Sed cu nobis ullamcorper. Has at doctus ponderum honestatis. In facer dicam corpora vis.";
    JTextArea myText = new JTextArea(alongString,10,100 );

    myText.setLineWrap(true);
    myText.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JPanel simplePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    simplePanel.add(myText, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.add(simplePanel);
    this.validate();
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);

}

public static final void main(String ... args) {
    new MyTest();
}
```

Comment: It's right it solve my problem. But in fact i have reduced the number of jtextarea and panel, but is the way more complicated  . . .
I will work on it, anyways ty

Comment: no problem, I only gave the simplePanel a layout (BorderLayout) this solved it. As best practice is to always define a layoutmanager to JPanel. good luck with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to put your JTextArea in a JScrollPane. If your JTextArea is loose in a parent container, the layout manager for the parent container determines the size of the JTextArea.

I'm not sure exactly what functionality you're looking for, but the following code fills the JFrame with the JTextArea. If the frame gets too small, scroll bars appear so all the text is visible.

I've removed the JTextArea constructor arguments for rows and columns. Note: the "columns" parameter does not mean how many letters will fit across. I don't know exactly what a "column" is, but it appears to be wider than a typical letter.

I've also removed "myPanel", and am adding the JScrollPane directly to the JFrame.

```
    String alongString = "Accusata consulatu vix ad, eruditi albucius liberavisse est no. Platonem reprehendunt qui ea. Dicta recteque referrentur an his, id facete maiorum vulputate vim. At suas oratio mnesarchum quo. Quidam omnium necessitatibus ex sea, vix soleat quaerendum conclusionemque ut, case malorum nam an.No quis suas discere nam, nam ex nostro fastidii vivendum. Sed cu nobis ullamcorper. Has at doctus ponderum honestatis. In facer dicam corpora vis.";
    JTextArea myText = new JTextArea(alongString);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myText);

    this.setSize(800, 600);

    myText.setLineWrap(true);
    myText.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    this.add(scrollPane);
    this.validate();
    this.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Hum, i don't understand why a JTextArea with unlimited space (he is alone and i can put more and more rows) can't wrap the line when the text is about to go outside of the frame.
If i put a scrollpane i will have a scroll for a text which can normally be display in the frame because there is free space.

Comment: Then don't use a FlowLayout (default JPanel LayoutManager) but a BorderLayout.